# Correlation coefficient between Sample mean and one of the sample?

Tags: self-study, correlation

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be the iid sample from $N(\theta,1)$.

Then how can I compute the correlation coefficient between sample mean $\bar X$ and $X_1$?

In order to get the $\rho$, I need to take care of $E[(X_1-\theta)(\bar X-\theta)]$, which equals $E(X_1\bar X)-\theta^2$.

To get $E(X_1\bar X)$, i need joint pdf of $\bar X$ and $X_1$, which requires $\rho$.

Where did I stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correlation coefficient is just the scaled covariance.  You have $\DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} \V \bar{X}=1/n$ and $\V X_1 = 1$.  That gives you the scaling, for the covariance we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}} \C(\bar{X}, X_1) = \E(\bar{X}-\theta)(X_1-\theta)
$$
where $\C$ is the covariance operator. For the calculation of the covariance there is no difference if we assume $\theta=0$ which simplifies. Then we can calculate
$$
\C(\bar{X}, X_1) = \E(\bar{X}-\theta)(X_1-\theta)= \E \bar{X}\cdot X_1 = \\
\E \frac1n\sum X_i \cdot X_1 = \frac1n \E \sum X_i X_1= \\
\frac1n \E X_1^2
$$
since all the terms in the sum for $i=2,3,\dots$ disappears.  You can take it from here!